# Magento attribute file upload

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to do a attribute what will be file upload (not image)?
I tryed like this:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'file',
    'label'=> 'Catalog Pdf',
    'input' => 'file',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'catalog_pdf', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

It's showing file upload in category, but probably something is wrong because after installation subcategories are not showing (ajax problem), and in frontend categories view I get "There has been an error processing your request"

Answer (score 0):

File upload attribute type is not present. So, the sql which run on setup is creating the issue

Try something like:
'type' => 'varchar',
'input' => 'image'

This makes input type as file upload but process it in default image processing
'backend_model' => 'xxx'

Here you can specify where this would be processed

Comment: in your custom backend model you have to define custom code for saving pdf file